# Wordpress 5.2.2 and selenium: Unable to locate the body post (a rich text editor that is not in iframe or TinyMCE)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and C#. I am trying to create a test to very that I can create a basic post in my Wordpress page. My test case failed because its unable to locate the rich text editor which is not in iframe or TinyMCE. Hope that anyone can help me on this. Thanks.

My test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Create_A_Basic_Post()
{
    LoginPage.GoTo();
    LoginPage.LoginAs("admin").WithPassword("hatran").Login();
    NewPostPage.GoTo();
    NewPostPage.CreatePost("This is the post title")
            .WithBody("Hi, This is the post body")
            .Publish();
    NewPostPage.GoToNewPost();
    Assert.AreEqual(PostPage.Title, "This is the post title", "Title did not match new post.");
}
```

The method causing error in my automation framework:

```
public void Publish()
{
    Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("post-title-0")).SendKeys(title);
    Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='components-autocomplete']/p[@aria-label='Empty block; start writing or type forward slash to choose a block']"))
    .SendKeys(body);
    Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text() = 'Publish…']")).Click();
}
```

I tried the following codes to locate the element and sendkeys but it didn't work

1. Simple code

Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='wpbody-content']/div[@class='components-autocomplete']/p[@aria-label='Empty block; start writing or type forward slash to choose a block']")).SendKeys(body);

OR 
2. Used IJavaScriptExecutor

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jscript = Driver.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
var postBody = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='components-autocomplete']/p[@aria-label='Empty block; start writing or type forward slash to choose a block']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.Instance;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'hello body post via javascript'", postBody);
```

Expected result: can create a new post with the title and body

Actual result: exception:

Message:

```
Test method WordpressTests.CreatePostTests.Can_Create_A_Basic_Post threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='components-autocomplete']/p[@aria-label='Empty block; start writing or type forward slash to choose a block']
```

[Source code of the new post page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDEkD.png)

[Another picture for the source of the rich text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFvoX.png)

[My test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fnav.png)

[Code to send text to the block editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECo0a.png)

Start writing or type / to choose a block

Comment: As you can see on the screenshot, there is a popup blocking the rich text editor, close it first. and then try to type your text

Comment: Hi Asanka, Thanks for your reply. I added code to close the popup and tried to send text to the rich text editor but sill not able to locate the editor (my XPath returned the element in Firefox developer tool). Note that I can locate the rich text editor using the nearly same code (Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='components-autocomplete']/p[@aria-label='Paragraph block']"))) when I view a post. I added more pictures for the source of the rich text editor and my code to the question for more clear. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Hi, I spent a lot of time on this. Finally, I figured it out. Key things are that I have to use actions and find element by XPath("//div[@class='editor-block-list__layout block-editor-block-list__layout']") as attached in the question. I tried to locate the block editor by different things but its only working with that one. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Good to hear you managed to resolve it